# Get daily averages of monthly database

Tags: python, date, numpy, scipy

I have a long list of data structured in the following way

```
Date, Time, Temperature, Moisture, Accumulated precipitation

1/01/2011, 00:00, 23, 50, 2,    
1/01/2011, 00:15, 22, 45, 1,   
1/01/2011, 00:30, 20, 39, 0,  
1/01/2011, 01:00, 25, 34, 0,  
1/01/2011, 01:15, 23, 50, 0,  
           .
           .
           .
           .
1/01/2011, 23:45, 22, 40, 0,
           .
           .
           .
           .
31/01/2011, 00:00, 23, 45, 0,
```

How I can get the daily averages of the variables `Temperature` and `Moisture` for the 31st day of the month?

Comment: Is this a text file you're getting the data from?

Answer (score 3):

This is the sort of thing that the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) library is good at.  The basic idea is that you can read data into objects called `DataFrames`, kind of like an Excel sheet, and then you can do neat things to them.  Starting from a `temps.csv` file I made up to look like yours:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("temps.csv", index_col=False, parse_dates=[[0,1]], skipinitialspace=True)
>>> df = df.rename(columns={"Date _Time": "Time"})
>>> df = df.set_index("Time")
>>> df
                     Temperature  Moisture  Accumulated precipitation
Time                                                                 
2011-01-01 00:00:00           23        50                          2
2011-01-01 00:15:00           22        45                          1
2011-01-01 00:30:00           20        39                          0
2011-01-01 01:00:00           25        34                          0
2011-01-01 01:15:00           23        50                          0
2011-01-01 23:45:00           22        40                          0
2011-01-02 00:00:00          123       250                         32
2011-01-02 00:15:00          122       245                         31
2011-01-02 00:30:00          120       239                         30
2011-01-02 01:00:00          125       234                         30
2011-01-02 01:15:00          123       250                         30
2011-01-02 23:45:00          122       240                         30
```

Once we have the frame in a nice shape, we can easily resample (the default is the mean):

```
>>> df.resample("D")
            Temperature  Moisture  Accumulated precipitation
Time                                                        
2011-01-01         22.5        43                        0.5
2011-01-02        122.5       243                       30.5
```

Or get the max or min:

```
>>> df.resample("D", how="max")
            Temperature  Moisture  Accumulated precipitation
Time                                                        
2011-01-01           25        50                          2
2011-01-02          125       250                         32
>>> df.resample("D", how="min")
            Temperature  Moisture  Accumulated precipitation
Time                                                        
2011-01-01           20        34                          0
2011-01-02          120       234                         30
```

Et cetera.  Note that this is just the brute average of the recorded data points each day: if you want to resample differently to account for the different distance between measurements, that's easy too.  If you're going to be doing data processing in Python, it's definitely worth reading through the [10 minute overview](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) to see if it might be helpful.

Comment: Use the suggestions on a different database, I did as follows:

Comment: df = pd.read_csv('path-tracks.csv', index_col= 'Date', parse_dates=[0])
Now try to get the daily sum as follows:

df.resample('D',how='sum')

i get the following:
         
 2004-02-06 155.8 -748.5 8 342 -369
 2004-02-07 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2004-05-29 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2004-05-30 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
 2004-05-31 92.9 -400.4 8 303 -181
 2004-06-01 94.2 -395.4 12 180 -180

I did something wrong? because it no takes into account the date 2004-02-05 6:45:00? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

Use the suggestions on a different database, I did as follows:

df = pd.read_csv('path-tracks.csv', index_col= 'Date', parse_dates=[0])
df

```
                  Lat    Lon  ID  Moisture  Temperature Category
```

Date
2004-02-05 06:45:00  19.7  -95.2   1        45          -38      CCM
2004-02-05 07:45:00  19.7  -94.7   1        34          -48      CCM
2004-02-05 08:45:00  19.3  -93.9   1        57          -60      CCM
2004-02-05 09:45:00  19.0  -93.5   1        89          -58      CCM
2004-02-05 10:45:00  19.0  -92.8   1        34          -50      CCM
2004-02-05 11:45:00  19.2  -92.6   1        23          -40      CCM
2004-02-05 12:45:00  19.9  -93.0   1        10          -43      CCM
2004-02-05 13:15:00  20.0  -92.8   1        50          -32      CCM
2004-05-30 04:45:00  23.1 -100.2   2        45          -45     SCME
2004-05-30 05:45:00  23.2 -100.0   2        68          -56     SCME
2004-05-30 06:45:00  23.3 -100.0   2        90          -48     SCME
2004-05-30 07:45:00  23.3 -100.2   2       100          -32     SCME
2004-05-31 03:15:00  23.4  -99.0   3        12          -36      SCM
2004-05-31 04:15:00  23.5  -98.9   3        34          -46      SCM
2004-05-31 05:15:00  23.6  -98.7   3        56          -68      SCM
2004-05-31 06:15:00  23.7  -98.8   3        78          -30      SCM

Now try to get the daily sum as follows:

df.resample('D',how='sum')

i get the following:

```
          Lat    Lon  ID  Moisture  Temperature
```

Date
2004-02-06  155.8 -748.5   8       342         -369
2004-02-07    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-08    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-09    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-10    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-11    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-12    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-13    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-14    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-15    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-16    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-17    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-18    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-19    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-20    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-21    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-22    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-23    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-24    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-25    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-26    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-27    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-28    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-02-29    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-01    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-02    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-03    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-04    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-05    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-06    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-07    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-08    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-09    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-10    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-11    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-12    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-13    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-14    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-15    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-16    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-17    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-18    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-19    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-20    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-21    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-22    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-23    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-24    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-25    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-26    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-27    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-28    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-29    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-30    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-03-31    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-01    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-02    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-03    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-04    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-05    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-06    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-07    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-08    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-09    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-10    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-11    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-12    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-13    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-14    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-15    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-16    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-17    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-18    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-19    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-20    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-21    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-22    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-23    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-24    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-25    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-26    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-27    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-28    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-29    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-04-30    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-01    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-02    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-03    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-04    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-05    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-06    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-07    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-08    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-09    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-10    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-11    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-12    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-13    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-14    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-15    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-16    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-17    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-18    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-19    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-20    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-21    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-22    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-23    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-24    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-25    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-26    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-27    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-28    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-29    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-30    NaN    NaN NaN       NaN          NaN
2004-05-31   92.9 -400.4   8       303         -181
2004-06-01   94.2 -395.4  12       180         -180

I did something wrong? because it no takes into account the date 2004-02-05 6:45:00? How do I fix this error?

Comment: This should be deleted and asked as a separate question, because it's not an answer to the original question.  StackOverflow works in a question/answer framework, not a threaded one.